# Can't change directories in terminal

Tags: macos, terminal.app

I am trying to make a hello world program work on my Mac. Every time I go to change a directory I get a message that says:

```
-bash: cd: documents No such file or directory exists.
```

I know the documents directory is there.

```
cd Documents
-bash: cd: documents: No such file or directory
```

Comment: What happens if you use `ls` from the root folder, can you see your target directory there?

Comment: `(Applications    home
    Library   installer.failurerequests
    Network    libpeerconnection.log
    System    net
   User Guides And Information private
   Users    sbin
    Volumes    sockets.log
    bin    tmp
    cores    usr
    dev    var
   etc`

Answer (score 2):

You're likely not starting from the correct directory. Try cd ~/Documents or cd /Users/(Your Username here)/Documents.

Also note that, depending on formatting of the disk, your filesystem may be Case Sensitive, meaning documents and Documents are two completely different locations.

Comment: -bash: syntax error near unexpected token

Comment: I keep getting that